# Embedded Live-Agent Chat Settings Offline support Case field selection

Tags: case, fields, chat, embedded, offline

I try to add new Case field by pressing plus sign. There are some set of Case fields selectable and to be used for Case form. I need Case description field and it is missing from selectable case fields set.
[image]

I do not know how the Case record selectable field set is originally produced and how do I define or add new case fields to this selectable Case field list. I need Case description field and it is not now selectable. How do I get Case description field to be selectable on the set?

Best Regards
Kari Makkonen

Comment: This issue has a remarkable business impact when you are not able to use needed Case fields. I can find from Salesforce Customize the Offline Support Form help documentation "You can add only fields that are available on the object." So my understanding is that all CASE object fields shoud be able to select for Chat and Case offline form fields?

Comment: This issue is opened also on Salesforce developer community  (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=General_Development&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9062I000000Xr3vQAC).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a field that's not currently supported in the Chat forms Description usually comes as a Long Text Area on Case.

According to a Salesforce Knowledge Article, only following field types are supported currently:

> - Email
> - Phone
> - Picklist (not including dependent picklist at this time)
> - Text

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316757&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) is the link for reference.